# 100% width = viewport width. How to make it as wide as is page body instead?

Tags: html, css

I have site which needs to display wide table. Above it is header which should be as wide as whole page (in this case, as wide as is table). However, it's only as wide as wide is viewport (screen size), so it looks alright when displayed, but as soon as user scrolls to sides he sees that header is not as wide as it should. How can I stretch this header to full page width without hardcoding values?

Simple example:

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>r</td>
      <td>y</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>w</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>e</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
div {background-color: red;height:20px;width:100%;}
td {width: 100px;min-width:100px;}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JXG5c/3/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fix is actually quite simple; wrap the table and the header in a `inline-block` `div`. This way, the wrapping `div` takes as much space as necessary, not just the space of the viewport. Then, you can use the 100% width for the child `div`, which is your header. So, your new markup should look something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>V</td><td>e</td><td>r</td><td>y</td><td></td><td>l</td><td>o</td> <td>n</td <td>g</td><td></td><td>t</td><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>l</td><td>e</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And your new CSS should look like this:

```
td {width: 100px;min-width:100px;}
#parent {display:inline-block;}
#child {background-color: red;height:20px;width:100%;}
```

So really all that needs to be done is that the parent must wrap the header and the table, and you need to set it to `inline-block`, and Voila, you have a full sized header. Also, note that the header will not be "fixed", it will scroll with the page, which if I interpreted your question correctly,
is what you want to happen.

Here's a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/JXG5c/24/

**UPDATE**: Why does this work with `inline-block` but not `block`?

`Block` automatically takes up all the space of the parent. The parent for your header is the viewport/body, which is automatically 100% of the screen size.

Using `inline-block`, however, causes the div to take as much space as necessary. Think of it like a `<span>` element; it takes up as much space as necessary, no more, no less. However, `div`s don't work well with `inline`, so the people at the W3C made `inline-block`, which confers `inline` behavior to any `block` element. By using inline-block, the parent div automatically fits to the size of the children, which are your table and header. Thus, the parent of the header is the same size as the table, and by setting the header to 100% the width of the parent, the issue is solved. :)

Comment: Great, this is what I needed! Do you mind to explain how does this work? Why it does not work with block, but it does with inline-block?

Comment: Is it possible to horizontally center the inline-block div?

Answer (score 4):

Have you thought of just posiitioning the header fixed?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37g2t/)**

```
body {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
div {
    background-color: red;
    height:20px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
td {
    width: 100px;
    min-width:100px;
}
```

**UPDATE**
If you want preserve vertical scrolling of the header use this jQuery snippet:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('div').css('top',-$(window).scrollTop());
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WCDb/)

**UPDATE**

Here is another, even simpler aproach but i could imagine that the above is better for you, at least if you cannot edit the output of the tables.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5bZh/)

Comment: Beware. With this solution header will be on same place when you scrolling your page.

Comment: Nice hack with inserting div into table. Take a upvote from me :D

Comment: Damn. I'm glad for help but I can't have fixed header, this question is for css & html solution only and last solution is equal to making whole page layout with tables. That's undesirable in these modern times. But I aknowledge I did not specify using tables for layout is forbidden so I will accept this as correct answer if nothing proper comes around.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think it should work http://jsfiddle.net/JXG5c/15/

```
 body {padding-top: 20px;}
div {background-color: red;height:20px;width: 100%;position: fixed;top: 0;}
td {width: 100px; min-width:100px;}
```

Comment: After edit it does, but it is the same solution with header fixed to the top of page.